# JPA Query for using single column for 2 columns in dersired output

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, graphql

**Transaction**:

| TID | TStatus | TDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 | 2020-02-20 |
| 3 | 2 | 2020-03-15 |

**AmountTable**:

| TID | amount |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 9874 |

Desired Output :

| Start | End | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-02-20 | 2020-03-15 | 9874 |

Start(transaction.tdate where tstatus=1),End(transaction.tdate where tstatus=2)

How to write the jpa query for that:
Something similar to JPA Repo

```
@Query(select new com.training.project t.TDate,t.TDate from Transaction t)
List <Report> fetchReport();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select t1.Tdate as Start, t2.Tdate as End, a.amount as Amount
from Transaction t1
         inner join Transaction t2 on t1.TID = t2.TID
         inner join Amount a on t1.TID = a.TID
where t1.TDate < t2.TDate
      and t1.status = 1
      and t2.status = 2
```

Comment: Worked like charm !!! 
Thanks Davide
Just worried about the time complexity that this might cause .

Comment: It shouldn't be too bad considering that it's a join between two tables on the id. But yes, you might want to consider keeping all the values in one table and update the same row. Or you could also try using views. You need to profile your app and see what works better.

Comment: Maybe you need to change the condiftion to `t1.TDate <= t2.TDate` or the query won't include transactions ending the same day. It really depends how long a transaction can last.

Comment: Please, accept the answer if it's the correct one